# Default alternative to Pixel Saver in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: display, screen, taskbar, titlebar

Is possible to have what [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) does without using it in Ubuntu 20.04? In other words, can I fuse activity bar and title bar in a natural way without extensions?

Comment: What is not OK with Pixel Saver? Why would you want another option which is not an extension?

Comment: @vanadium PixelSaver and No Title Bar are so extremely unreliable (sometimes not removing the title bar, different behaviors and incompatibilities across gnome versions, double or even triple window control buttons and sometimes even showing none ... it's so annoying) that a native Ubuntu maintained function would be definitely and without question favoured by me. Plus, with Ubuntu 20.04 none of them is capable of removing the plenty space wasted in the terminal ...

Comment: I have no issues whatsoever with Pixelsaver, which I am using myself since oktober (I used to have the top bar on the bottom before). Still, I fully agree with you that such functionality should be integrated in the desktop.